# Komodo edit 8 - Python3 user input

Tags: python-3.x, komodoedit

I am having on going issues with this new editor to try and run code with user input.  I have selected the python3 interpreter in the preferences: /usr/local/bin/python3

I have also set a shebang at the top of a .py file and I am using the following in my run command -

%(python) "-u" "%F"

However, I am still unable to use input() in my code. In the Komodo Edit Command output from this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print ("Name please?")
name = input()
print ("Hello ", name)
print ("Finish script...")
```

I get the following:

```
Name please?
('Hello ', <built-in function input>)
Finish script...
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but i'm stumped :(

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:-

```
print ("Name please?")
name = input()
```

Try this:-

```
name=input("Name Please?")
```